# Specific use of OpenHFT's Chronicle-DeCentered ../examples/appreciation/ demonstration ... how?

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-map, blockchain.info-api

How to use the 5 .sh scripts to demonstrate Chronicle's BlockChain Ledger tefchnology ...

./run.shm & #params needed?

```
16467@DESKTOP-EQDBIQA> pwd
/c/Users/16467/git/Chronicle-Decentred/examples/appreciation
16467@DESKTOP-EQDBIQA> l
./   appreciation.iml  cp.txt   run.sh*  start_peer.sh*        start_traffic.sh*
../  bench.sh*         pom.xml  src/     start_peer_graal.sh*  target/
16467@DESKTOP-EQDBIQA> ./run.sh
```

I expect a set of processes to execute, showcasing low-latency merits of Chronicle's BlockChain Ledger technology.

```
16467@DESKTOP-EQDBIQA> ./run.sh
Starting  with params
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project appreciation: An exception occured while executing the Java class. town.lost.examples.appreciation.benchmark. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]
```

[https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=329725524639534&set=a.329612584650828&type=3&theater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8HzA.jpg)

Comment: matter being addressed at https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Decentred/issues/4#issuecomment-511218952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a note that only Java 8 is supported. This doesn't appear to work with Java 11 due to third party libraries we use.

Comment: Thanks! got the tests working under ExchangeMarketTest with jdk8.   You are telling a HUGE story here --> https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Decentred/blob/master/README.adoc  maybe a YouTube video could help guide newbies on Chronicle's BlockChain Ledger Technology?